# Video Will Not Work On IE8

Tags: javascript, html, object, video, internet-explorer-8

Here is my code:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"    codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="322" height="266" align="Default*">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain">
<param name="movie" value="Pro Tools Tutorials.swf">
<param name="quality" value="high">
<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff">
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
<embed src="videos/Pro Tools Tutorials.swf" quality="high"  align="middle"  bgcolor="#ffffff"  width="250" height="230" allowFullScreen="true" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried it with other browsers? and does it work?

Try changing this line:

```
<param name="movie" value="videos/Pro Tools Tutorials.swf">
```

and make sure you are locating in a proper path i suggest also you try to play the video in its direct path i.e (http://localhost/ < path of file >)